# Default the page focus to address bar

Tags: javascript, html, address-bar

After the page redirect the focus is removed from address bar of the browser.
But I want that after redirect my new page should be loaded and the focus to be to the address bar of the browser.

Is it possible using HTML/javascript?

I hope my question is clear, Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 2):

No, I believe this is not possible.